# How can I Multiply two columns then add them together easily?

Tags: excel-2019

I would like to Multiply Column A with Column B.  There is data for each column in rows 3-20.

Rather than doing (A3*B3)+...(A20*B20), is there an easier and more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that in my question, it did not show the asterisk for multiplication, it should be something like...
(A3 x B3) + ... (A20 x B20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just figured it out.  What I want to do can be accomplished with the SUMPRODUCT forumula.

=SUMPRODUCT(Select Column A Values,Select Column B Values)